# How do I draw a line using IO ports when making an operating system for x86 systems?

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, inline-assembly

I am making a kernel in C, but I was wondering how i could use the `outb` instruction in AT&T syntax assembly (the as command on linux) to draw graphics. I plan to place the assembly as inline assembly in my kernel.

In a quick summary, I am trying to use inline assembly in C to be able to draw something like this for my kernel:
[image: slkdkfhsjkdlfhskdjf]

Also I am trying to make my OS for x86 CPUs

Comment: It will depend on the specification of the device you are planning to send data via `outb` instruction.

Comment: Are you using a specific graphical display, or are you relying on the standard PC architecture, with BIOS, (S)VGA card, and so on?

Comment: relying on the standard PC architecture with BIOS @Wisblade

Comment: Was that drawn by your own OS kernel using the BIOS interrupt `0x10` calls? If not, use them, but otherwise you'll need reference material for the graphics card to know how to control the device.

Comment: No its from somewhere i found in google images... @WeatherVane

Comment: In that case I suggest using the BIOS calls to get you going. The question can't be answered except by a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

So, basically, you're trying to do what we (those who are old enough...) did when DOS ruled the world: using Mode 13h and SVGA from custom libraries...

The "outb" problem isn't one. In fact, since you rely on standard PC architecture, you won't need it. You'll write directly in video card's framebuffer, and for that, you'll need so basic primitives:

- A full documentation for interruption 10h. "PC System Programming", by Michael Tischer, is quite everything you need.
- Start/end video mode: usual ones are mode 13h (320x200x256), VGA (640x480x16), SVGA (640x480x256 and more). Honestly, 256 color modes are easier to program. Something to erase screen, too.
- Line drawing primitives: horizontal (very fast), vertical (fast), random (Bresenham's algorithm).
- Rectangle drawing primitives (filled or not).
- Circle/ellipse drawing primitives (Bresenham's algorithm).
- A bitmap font. You can use the one present in your video card, or draw one by yourself. It's however easier to use first a fixed width font.
- A primitive to output one char at a given position on screen, then another primitive to output a string.
- Primitives to copy/paste/move rectangular zones within framebuffer.
- Primitives to read/write the entire palette for 256 (or less) color modes.
- All primitives should take one or more color parameter (outline/filling usually).

All these primitives are really easy to implement in pure assembler. You should start with mode 13h, so you won't have to deal with segmentation or latches first.

Once you'll have all these primitives, drawing something like the screen you presented will be trivial: drawing 5 lines, output 3 strings (even if one is multiple characters output with color change) and put two bitmaps/symbols.

For example, my (very...) old `PutPixel` Pascal procedure was like this, for mode 13h (16-bit assembler):

```
Procedure PutPixel ( X,Y : Word ; Color : Byte ) ; Assembler ;
ASM
   mov ax,319
   cmp ax,X
   jc @end
   mov ax,199
   cmp ax,Y
   jc @end
   mov ax,$A000
   mov es,ax
   mov ax,320
   mul Y
   add ax,X
   mov di,ax
   mov al,COLOR
   mov es:[di],al
@end:
END;
```

And this is a procedure for end user, i.e. it has some basic parameters validation... Internal pixel settings were without these tests.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts:

a) Setting up a video mode. This can be done using the firmware (BIOS on old computers, or UEFI on current computers) which mostly uses video card specific code provided by a video card's ROM; or it can be done using your own video card specific code (a driver) that matches the video card (if you feel like spending 50 years writing drivers for all the different video cards). The result of setting up a video mode is a "frame buffer" - part of the video card's memory that is mapped into the CPU's physical address space, which contains the data for each pixel (its color) that the video card sends to the monitor. For how to do this, you need to choose a method (BIOS, UEFI, your own code for which video card) and research and/or ask about that method.

b) Writing data (drawing new colors for pixels) to the video card's frame buffer. This is almost always done using (faster) memory writes and not (slow) IO ports. For how to do this, it depends on how the video mode was set up. Often it's a linear frame buffer, which is very simple - it's like an array of pixels at a certain (physical) address. Sometimes (especially for obsolete junk), it's not and you have to deal with the frame buffer being split into banks or planes where you can only access one bank or one plane at a time and need special code to switch between banks or planes.